# Magento 2 Custom Tab on Customer Account

Tags: magento2, customer-account, tabs

I'm trying to add a custom tab on Customer Account Frontend.

I've successfully added the link but when clicking it all I get is a blank page.

There is no clue in the logs.

This is what I have

customer_account.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <!-- Add custom links -->
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-subscriptions-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tab Name</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">frontName/controller</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

frontname_controller_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content"  cacheable="false">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\BlockClass"
                   name="name"
                   template="Company_module::templateName.phtml"
            />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Controller

```
class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Title'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Block

```
class BlockClass extends Template
{
    /**
     * Subscriptions constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<h1>It Works!</h1>
```

I should point out that the right controller is called. Given that the right title is set to the page. Yet no html is displayed.

What am I missing. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

In **frontname_controller_index.xml**

Setting the layout attribute of the page node as follows

**layout="admin-2columns-left"**

was causing the undesired behaviour. How did I end up with this, I'm not really sure. I blame it on copy-pasting in a hurry.

Basically all I had to was remove the layout attribute on the page node.
Changing it to "2columns-left" works as well.