# Add new link in my account (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, customer-account, page, link

I am trying to add `refer a friend` link in the customer account page.
I followed these links.

> [Add new link to customer account page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208410/add-new-link-to-customer-account-page)
>
> [Magento 2 Custom Tab on Customer Account](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203360/magento-2-custom-tab-on-customer-account?rq=1)

It doesnt work for me

`customer_account.xml`

```
 <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="refer-a-friend">
      <arguments>
       <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/refer</argument>
       <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Refer a Friend</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

`routes.xml` in `app/code/YX/Customer/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
     <route frontName="yx_customer" id="yx_customer">
         <module name="YX_Customer"/>
     </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

`customer_refer_index.xml` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_refer_index.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <update handle="customer_account"/>
   <body>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="YX\Customer\Block\Friend"
               name="referFriend"
              template="Magento_Customer::account/refer_a_friend.phtml"
        />
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

Block file in `app/code/YX/Customer/Block/Friend`

```
class Friend extends Template
 {

   public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
      parent::__construct($context);
    }
 }
```

Controller `app/code/YX/Customer/Controller/Refer/Index.php`

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {

   protected $resultPageFactory;


   public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
  ) {
      $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
      parent::__construct($context);
   }


   public function execute()
   {
      return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
   }
 }
```

`refer-a-friend.phtml`

```
<div > Hello this is my template. I can do anything inside this file.</div>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path url and your layout file name are incorrect. Your frontName in `routers.xml` is yx_customer and not customer.

> customer_account.xml

```
 <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="refer-a-friend">
  <arguments>
   <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">yx_customer/refer</argument>
   <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Refer a Friend</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

And your layout file should be named `yx_customer_refer_index.xml`

Comment: I had a similar problem, issue was with layout file name and missing route.xml, took sometime to figure this out.